# How to change doxygen formatting style in Resharper?

Tags: c++, resharper, doxygen

Resharper C++ 2017 can generate doxygen headers for functions, classes, and everything else.

However, it writes the commands with the `\` prefix, and to keep a consistency with my project's other modules, I need to use the `@` prefix instead.

I assume that it is possible, since the command is called *Document (using 'doc' live template)* .

**How to change doxygen formatting style in resharper?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You change it like you would any other live template - via `ReSharper | Tools | Templates Explorer`. Select the C++ scope and update the 'doc' template in the Visual Studio editor to your preference. Take a look at the [Creating and Editing Templates](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Templates__Creating_and_Editing_Templates.html) help section for more info.